# MongoDB Java Driver Filter Integer Value of a String

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have MongoDB Document parameter of type "real" number but is represented in the DB as a string- e.g `"cId"="200"` instead of `"cId"=200`I have to query the DB for a range of numbers; e.g. filter equivalent to `SELECT ALL where cId is less than 10 and greater than 5.`

Is there a way to query the integer value of this parameter using a similar functional equivalent to `Integer.parseInt(str);` for example

My filter looks like

```
Bson filter = Filters.and(Filters.gt("cId", "0"), Filters.lt("cId","4"));
```

I'm hoping for an equivalent of something like

```
Bson filter = Filters.and(Filters.gt("cId", valueOf("0")), Filters.lt("cId",valueOf("4")));
```

Thanks...

Comment: You can convert the data into your db to store real number instead of string, is that a possibility?

Comment: hi @CharchitKapoor that is the "nuclear" option. we're trying to avoid that

Comment: Ok, so at present, you have strings and you are applying filters, by passing strings is that accurate?

Comment: correct, if i pass in an integer the DB/filter will not match anything

Comment: Then the best thing is to write an aggregation pipeline, convert your `cId` to a number within the pipeline using `$convert` https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/ and then match it using your parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting @CharchitKapoor comment above as the best available answer within the limitations of my question.... (however in my case, I ended up converting the data on insertion to a real number)

The best thing is to write an aggregation pipeline, convert your cId to a number within the pipeline using $convert mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert and then match it using your parameter